# Having Trouble Getting Started on Heroku with Python

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip

I am setting up a backend for my website with Heroku and Python. By doing so I am following Heroku's setup. But my problem arose at this step [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#run-the-app-locally).

when I try to run: `python3 manage.py collectstatic`

I get the following below:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 188, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 105, in collect
    for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 125, in list
    for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 23, in get_files
    directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 313, in listdir
    for entry in os.listdir(path):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/aaronmiller/Development/python-getting-started/static'
```

I have tried the following the instructions step by step and always get stuck at the part above. With:

```
    MacOS            10.14
    Python           2.7.15
    Python           3.7.2
    psql(PostgreSQL) 11.0 


    pip3 list
    Package         Version
    --------------- -------
    dj-database-url 0.5.0  
    Django          2.1.4  
    django-heroku   0.3.1  
    gunicorn        19.9.0 
    pip             18.1   
    psycopg2        2.7.6.1
    pytz            2018.7 
    setuptools      40.6.3 
    wheel           0.32.3 
    whitenoise      4.1.2  



    heroku pg:info
    === DATABASE_URL
    Plan:                  Hobby-dev
    Status:                Available
    Connections:           0/20
    PG Version:            10.6
    Created:               2018-12-31 18:40 UTC
    Data Size:             7.6 MB
    Tables:                0
    Rows:                  0/10000 (In compliance)
    Fork/Follow:           Unsupported
    Rollback:              Unsupported
    Continuous Protection: Off
```

Let me know if there is any other info I can provide and I will.

> Update

I stopped trying this with python 2 and then I took out the code below that I added to settings.py

```
# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: what shows up when you type `python --version` in your command line on heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `django-heroku` package requires Python 3, see the README file: https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku/blob/master/README.rst

edit: It seems you have python3 available on your system, so try just running the following:

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

You'll need to re-install any dependencies you installed for python2 (presumably, using `pip`) for the python3 environment. Do you have `pip3` available?

Comment: Hey, thanks for noticing this. I have update the question and am using python3 now

Comment: @AaronMiller Well technically it's entirely different question now :) But the error is quite clear: `'No such file or directory: /Users/aaronmiller/Development/python-getting-started/static'`

Comment: Thank you very much! It is now working. After I posted this I put some code in 'settings.py' in hopes it would work; However, after taking it out it now works!